# Magento 2 get catalog rule for current product

Tags: magento2, product, product-page, catalog-rules

I would like to get the current **catalog rule** for the **product** on the **product page**. I want to be able to output the name on the page.

I know this is possible in magento 1 but cannot find any function in code for magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

This table `catalogrule_product` holds all the catalog rules applied to a particular product with the discount amount.

You could use this resource model 
`Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule::getRulesFromProduct($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId)` to get rules applied to a product.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Sample extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule
     */
    protected $ruleResource;

    ...

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule $rule
    ) {
        ...
        $this->ruleResource = $rule;
        ...
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @param int|string $date
     * @param int $websiteId
     * @param int $customerGroupId
     * @param int $productId
     */
    public function getRules($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId)
    {
        ...
        /** @var [] $rules catalog rules */
        $rules = $this->ruleResource->getRulesFromProduct($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

class Rule extends \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule
{

```
public function getRuleByProduct($product){
    $priceRules = null;
    $rd = null;
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
    $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
    $dateTs = $this->_localeDate->scopeTimeStamp($storeId);
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();

    if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
        $customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    }

    $cacheKey = date('Y-m-d', $dateTs) . "|{$websiteId}|{$customerGroupId}|{$productId}|{$price}";


    $rules =  $this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $product->getId());

    if (!array_key_exists($cacheKey, self::$_priceRulesData)) {
        $rulesData = $this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
        if ($rulesData) {
            foreach ($rulesData as $ruleData) {
                if ($product->getParentId()) { 
                    $rd = $ruleData['rule_id'];
                    $priceRules = $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price;
                    if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    $rd = $ruleData['rule_id'];
                    $priceRules = $this->_catalogRuleData->calcPriceRule(
                        $ruleData['action_operator'],
                        $ruleData['action_amount'],
                        $priceRules ? $priceRules : $price
                    );
                    if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = $rd;
        } else {
            self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = null;
        }
    } else {
        return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey];
    }
    return null;

    return $rules;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I get current products rules by the following way:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $ruleResourceModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
        $customerGroupId = 0;
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        }
        $rules = $ruleResourceModel->getRulesFromProduct(date('Y-m-d'),
                                                          $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
                                                                 $customerGroupId, $product->getId());
        if(!empty($rules)){
            $catalogRuleRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogRule\Api\CatalogRuleRepositoryInterface');
            $rule = $catalogRuleRepository->get($rules[0]['rule_id']);
}
```

Above is just starting point for any one who is interested in it. you can modify it as per your need. you can inject classes instead of using object Manager